# Proving a function is order-isomorphic?

Tags: order-theory

> Let $A$ be a chain and $B$ be a partially ordered set. Let $f: A \rightarrow B$ be a 1-1 function for which $a \leq b$ implies $f(a) \leq f(b)$. Prove $f$ is order-isomorphic.

Let $f: A \rightarrow B$.

Let $x_0, x_1 \in A, f(x_0), f(x_1) \in B$.

Then $f(x_0) = f(x_1) \Longrightarrow x_0 = x_1$. So $f$ is order-isomorphic under $=$.

Now let $f(x_0) < f(x_1)$, so $x_0 \neq x_1$. But $A$ is a chain, so either $x_0 < x_1$ or $x_1 < x_0$. Suppose $x_1 < x_0 \rightarrow f(x_0) < f(x_1)$. What now?

Comment: Do you mean $f(x_1) < f(x_0)$ at the end?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan No, I am trying to prove that can't happen by contradiction.

Comment: But don't you know that $x_1 < x_0 \Rightarrow f(x_1)\leq f(x_0)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key observation here is that $x_1<x_0$ implies $x_1\le x_0,$ which implies by hypothesis that $f(x_1)\le f(x_0).$ Hence, you have $f(x_1)\le f(x_0)<f(x_1),$ which cannot happen in a partially ordered set.